# VSEPR Theory and Predicting Shapes of N2F2

Tags: electrons, molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

I had asked a question on a IA Past Paper:

> Predict the structure of $\ce{N2F2}$ using VSEPR Theory.

Now I'm not that strong at VSEPR theory. For the most part, I understand it when it involves a central atom and a ligand, but how does it work for other molecules, for example:

$$\ce{N2F2}$$

Any clearer understanding of this or any help learning about the specifics of VSEPR theory, as in how it is generally use regarding or irregular molecules, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Point your finger at one of the nitrogens and pretend this is the central atom.

Comment: Have you drawn the Lewis structure?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you understand VSEPR theory (which is around a central atom, and actually yes! That's all you need to know to answer this) , you know that first of all you have to draw the *Lewis structure* of the compound, which you can draw [like this](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ms-android-lenovo&ei=w-ktWenAEoT0vgTIlonYDA&q=n2f2%20lewis%20structure&oq=n2f2&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.35i39k1j0l4.8642.10873.0.12019.7.6.0.2.2.0.257.952.2-4.4.0....0...1.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..2.5.801.3..0i131k1j0i20k1j0i10k1.s8h2XdRGWbY) and now you have got the preliminary linear structure of the molecule $\ce{N2F2}$.

**Here, FYI, there might be a mistake. It can be done by considering $\ce{N2F2}$ to be analogues to $\ce{NF3}$, or anything pyramidal-like that which is totally wrong!**

Now you just have to apply the VSEPR theory on the $\ce{F-N=N}$ moiety in the left side and then on the $\ce{N=N-F}$ moiety in the right side(which is now your cup of tea!). And after applying the VSEPR theory you will get [these two structures](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Cistrans-Distickstoffdifluorid.png/440px-Cistrans-Distickstoffdifluorid.png) and both these isomers do exist!

Comment: Please comply with the homework policy. Don't give complete answers

Comment: @Pritt Balagopal Yes, see that's why I just have given the outline of how will he proceed, I haven't explained in details how will he apply the VSEPR theory on the mentioned two moieties. And if that goes against the homework policy then I will keep this in mind next time. Thank you.

Comment: Based on your answer, he doesn't have to see all that, you already mentioned the *cis* and *trans* isomers to him. He wouldn't need more.

Comment: Okay! Now I got the point. I'll keep it mind.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to treat both of the nitrogen atoms as central atoms. Each nitrogen has 4 electron pairs. However, because two of these pairs are in a double bond each nitrogen atom could be treated as having 3 electron pairs. This leaves two possible configurations: trigonal pyramidal and trigonal planar. Trigonal planar is the preferred structure because the repulsions between the other nitrogen and the adjacent fluorine are too high in the trigonal pyramidal structure.